# TypeError, captureStream is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video-recording, recordrtc

I have created a HTML5 page with video element. A sample video is played. After I had tried to record the stream in the video element. I am using the RecordRTC library for recording functionality. I have the following code

```
var stream = document.getElementById("my_video").captureStream();
var recorder = RecordRTC(stream, { 
  type: 'video'
});

recorder.startRecording();
```

The recording is successfully working on Chrome browser and Mozilla browser till version 57. But in last January , Mozilla browser updated to version 58. After this update, I got error when trying to record video using Mozilla.

The error message is:

```
TypeError 
message: document.getElementById("my_video").captureStream is not a function"
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, [according to the docs this is experimental tech](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream#Browser_compatibility) so Firefox requires you to prefix `moz` to the function name: `mozCaptureStream`. I'm a little surprised it worked at all previously.

You can check for the browser version with [`navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator).

```js
const sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;

if (sUsrAg.indexOf('Firefox') > -1) {
  console.log('Firefox');
  document.getElementById("my_video").mozCaptureStream();
} else {
  console.log('Other');
  document.getElementById("my_video").captureStream();
}
```

```html
<video id="my_video"></video>
```

Comment: thanks andy, Based on doc it is captureStream(). Is any chance to change method name to any other?

Comment: I have the same issue. Followed the above instruction but faced error 
 `canvasElt.mozCaptureStream is not a function:TypeError'

Comment: I am using FireFox

Comment: I think there is not need to check the user agent, which is also not a safe way to test this since the user agent can be changed by the user. We can simply check if `video.captureStream` exists with an if / else block or with a ternary operator `stream = video.captureStream ? video.captureStream() : video.mozCaptureStream();`.